# Make things depending on file extension

Tags: if-statement, makefile, gnu-make

I try to make one thing or another depending if a file has extension `p.md` or `md`:

```
$(DST)/%.md.html: $(SRC)/%.md $(TMPHTML5)
    $(eval EXT := $(suffix $<)) 
    ifeq('$(EXT)','.p.md')
        $(PANDOC_MD_HTML) -o $@ $< -V filename=$(<F) -V otherformatspresentations=true
    else
        $(PANDOC_MD_HTML) -o $@ $< -V filename=$(<F)
    endif
```

but I get:

```
make site/ESPA4.Dia-0-presentacio.p.md.html -B
ifeq('.md','.p.md')
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `'.md','.p.md''
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `ifeq('.md','.p.md')'
make: *** [Makefile:103: site/ESPA4.Dia-0-presentacio.p.md.html] Error 1
```

Comment: The build commands are run by the shell, not make, so you need to use shell commands, not make commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just use one pattern per type of file you want to create, as make was intended to be used?

```
$(DST)/%.p.md : $(SRC)/%.md $(TMPHTML5)
        $(PANDOC_MD_HTML) -o $@ $< -V filename=$(<F) -V otherformatspresentations=true
$(DST)/%.md : $(SRC)/%.md $(TMPHTML5)
        $(PANDOC_MD_HTML) -o $@ $< -V filename=$(<F)
```

Note that depending on which version of GNU make you're using order may or may not be important but this will work with all versions.

If you want to do it in one rule you can't use `ifeq` etc.  That is a *make* command, and everything in the recipe is passed to the *shell*.  The shell doesn't know anything about `ifeq` hence your errors.  You'll have to either use the `$(if ...)` function or else use shell syntax completely:

```
$(DST)/%.md.html: $(SRC)/%.md $(TMPHTML5)
        $(PANDOC_MD_HTML) -o $@ $< -V filename=$(<F) $(if $(filter %.p.md,$<),-V otherformatspresentations=true)
```

Or:

```
$(DST)/%.md.html: $(SRC)/%.md $(TMPHTML5)
        other=; case $< in (*.p.md) other="-V otherformatspresentations=true" ;; esac; \
        $(PANDOC_MD_HTML) -o $@ $< -V filename=$(<F) $$other
```

Comment: what do you mean with "Note that depending on which version of GNU make you're using order may or may not be important but this will work with all versions."? What's the best order?

Comment: Last solution does not work: `pandoc ... -o site/activitat.Phone-Home.p.md.html src/activitat.Phone-Home.p.md -V filename=activitat.Phone-Home.p.md $other`

Comment: The penultimate solution neither: `pandoc ... -o site/activitat.Phone-Home.p.md.html src/activitat.Phone-Home.p.md -V filename=activitat.Phone-Home.p.md `

Comment: Sorry I was comparing `$@` but forgetting it had the `.html` ending.  I changed the examples to compare with `$<` instead which doesn't have that ending.  Should work now.  Note that the second version _will_ show `$other` on the command line but it will work as that variable will be set to the extra option.  As for the other, the best order is the one I gave: that will work in all versions of GNU make.  If you reverse the order then will only work in versions of GNU make 3.82 and above.